# Getting Carrierwave working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, carrierwave, image-uploading

I tried following Railscast #253 for File Uploads and then a little bit of the README on the Carrierwave github site, but I feel like I'm missing a crucial middle step. I'm new to the whole Rails thing, and I wanted each user to have a profile picture, or "avatar", as I called it.

In my `_form.html.erb` file, I have the following:

```
    <%= form_for(@user), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
      <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
    <% end %>
```

In my `show.html.erb`, I have:

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb) if @user.avatar? %>
```

which I'm not even sure is right.

My `avatar_uploader.rb` is the same almost as when I created it,

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "/images/"
  end


  version :thumb do
    process :scale => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end
end
```

In my form, when I try it upload it, it accepts the image, I think. It doesn't show up in the image folder, or in the show page. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or an extra thing I should be doing that I missed? I have ImageMagick installed and RMagick included in my `Gemfile`, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing that either.

Edit:
I also have `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader` in my `user.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Include

```
mount_uploader :image,AvatarUploader
```

in user model

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am confident that this can solve his issue. Maybe i can present it in better way

Comment: I did do that, I forgot to post it. But since it is called `:avatar` in my table, I had `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Nope its correct,in ur form u have `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>` its used for displaying image, u dont have `form_for` how are u using `f.file_field`? u didnt show that in ur ques?

Comment: `"/images/` u are missing closing quote or is it a typo?